# Как правильно прописать отношения в сущности?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

Есть класс "UserTrainee"- он не является сущностью "Стажер". У стажера сущность User. UserTrainee как промежуточный класс для запросов. У него есть поле user и поле traineeId(стажер). Таблица user_trainee выглядит так:

id (bigint, PK),
userId (bigint, FK, not null),
traineeId (bigint, FK, not null)

Пример таблицы, которая должна будет получиться (вместо имен, их id соответственно):
[image: Пример таблицы]

Как это реализовать? Какие отношения прописывать в коде?
У меня что-то вроде этого получилось, не уверен, что делаю правильно:
В классе User:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<UserTrainee> userSet;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "traineeId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<UserTrainee> userTraineeSet;
```

В классе UserTrainee:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "trainee_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private User traineeId;
```

Comment: Абсолютно неверный подход.

Comment: А какой будет верный?